# Node.js -- Can't access static files while inside of route folder

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

My static files work perfectly on any route in app.js. But my static files aren't loading for any routes that I have in my /routes/blog.js file.

```
  Folder structure:

  Project
  ├── app.js 
  │ 
  │ 
  ├── public 
      └──  bootstrap...  
      └──  img...
  │
  │  
  ├──views
      └── index.html
      └── 404.html
      └── etc..
  │ 
  │ 
  ├──routes
       └── blog.js
```

Here's my app.js file

```
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express(); 
  const path = require('path'); 
  const blog = require('./routes/blog') 
  //Couple other requires...


  // Middleware
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use('/blog', blog)


  // Various get routes...



  // Start our server on port 3000
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Node app listening on port 3000...'));
```

Here's my /routes/blog.js file

```
  const express = require('express'); 
  const router = express.Router(); 


  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('blog.html');
  });


  // Post a blog post
  router.route('/post')
    .get( (req, res) => {
    res.render('post.html');
    })

    .post( (req, res, next) => {
       //STUFF
    res.redirect('/blog');
    });

  module.exports = router;
```

When I view page source on any page that goes through the app.js file my  point to htttp://localhost:3000/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css/ but when I view source for any page that goes through the blog.js file (for example if I go to localhost:3000/blog/post) my  point to htttp://localhost:3000/blog/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css/ and the static files don't load

Answer (score 0):

Add to your routes.js

```
const DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'routes');
```

and change the `get` to:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render(path.join(DIR, 'blog.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

to just

`app.use(express.static('public'));`